# Why does Apache POI read the row which has been manually erased?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am trying to figure out why the row on excel gets uploaded which is manually erased(NOT Row delete from right click). Here is the scenario:
PS-  I have a logic to trace the empty rows. If no of blank == myColumnCount, I skip the row. Somehow the blank count goes at least greater than 0. Hence gets uploaded

1. I enter the first row data
2. I enter the second row
3. I erase the cells manually of the second row
4. The data remains only on the first row
5. I save the file and upload it, POI reads the second row as empty row.
   I understand the concept of Physical number of rows but confused as to why this scenario returns the row which has no data ?

Comment: `The data remains only on the first row` and `POI reads the second row as empty row` should tell you enough

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I have a logic to trace the empty rows. If no of blank == myColumnCount, I skip the row. Somehow the blank count goes at least greater than 0. Hence gets uploaded

Comment: How do you count the blanks?

Comment: cell == null || cell.getCellType()==Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK

Comment: Then how exactly do you `I erase the cells manually of the second row`?

Comment: Select those cells and delete. If I delete the entire row from options I don't get this issue.

Comment: You use the `DEL` button for it?

Comment: Yes I use delete button

Comment: you should probably check for `cell.getStringCellValue().equals("")` as well